# Attaching an drawable image to email in android

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent, drawable

I have a list of Drawable images in my application and want to send one of the images through mail.
my code looks like

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Picture");                       
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse(lstPhotos.get(newPosition).getPhotoURL()));
myActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

But in the above code i have a problem since i cannot get the image URI from the list of drawables.
Can anyone help me how to send the image because if i use the above code i am getting an empty image of 0kb sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by saving that image to a temporary location on internal/external *cache* directory as an image and then use that image's path in the attachment using **Uri**.