# Android: how to attach a resource drawable to an email?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm trying to send an image drawable as an email attachment using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "foo@bar.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum...");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    startActivity(intent);
```

However I am given a message that the file does not exist. What am I missing here?

Comment: never tried it, but may be you could convert the drawable to a bitmap and then attach the bitmap ?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654576/attaching-an-drawable-image-to-email-in-android?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an URI to your own application resources. The application receiving this `Intent` isn't allowed to access this file.

Try placing this file on your sdcard en send that location as `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`

Answer (score 0):

Use [CWAC-Provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) so that you can pass a content URI that points at your resources.