# Add image to `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending a sms to multiple recipients using `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strMessage);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(getPhoneNumbers())));
        startActivity(intent);
```

However now I want to add a image to the sms. Is there any way to do this with `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` I tried adding below code with no success....

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://packagename/" + R.drawable.icon);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        intent.setType("image/png");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537933/android-how-to-attach-a-resource-drawable-to-an-email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email with attachment using SENDTO on some devices doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946297/sending-email-with-attachment-using-sendto-on-some-devices-doesnt-work)